# How to Pass Props from a GrandChild Component to a Child Component, and in turn to a Parent Component in React Native using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-props, react-state

I'm having a hard time trying to pass the value of the TextInput and DropDown Lists from a Child Component to a Parent Component, but in turn the DropDown Lists are sitting as Child Components in the Modal where the TextInput is located.

I tried to implement solutions that I found in online documentations with similar approaches,
but I didn't get any progress in my purpose. I'm a newbie to React native programming.

On the other hand, I'm expecting onPress SAVE (<TouchableOpacity>SAVE</TouchableOpacity>) to pass the TextInput and DropDown Lists value from the Child Component to the Form (<Text>{value}</Text>, <Text>{name}</Text>, <Text>{...}</Text> and <Text>{...}</Text>) sitting in the Parent Component.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide in getting this issue solved.

Here you have my HomeTeamInfo.tsx code which is the Parent Component:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
  GestureResponderEvent,
  Image,
  ImageBackground,
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  useColorScheme,
} from 'react-native';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import TeamLogo from '../assets/Icons/TeamLogo1.png';
import {Formik} from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import FlatButton from './Button';
import {colors} from './colors';
import {NativeStackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {RootStackParamList} from '../StackFirst/ScreenMode';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import AddPlayer from '../PlayersPick/AddPlayer';

const titleSchema = yup.object().shape({
  title: yup
    .string()
    .required('Team Name is required')
    .matches(
      /[A-Za-z]+/,
      'Type the right Format (at least one letter is a must)',
    )
    .min(2, 'Should be a minimum of 2 characters')
    .max(14, 'Should be a maximum of 18 characters'),
});

type propsType = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'HomeTeamInfo'>;

const HomeTeamInfo = (props: propsType) => {
  const {route} = props;
  const {value} = route.params;

  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const [visible, setIsVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [image, setImage] = useState<string>('https://ibb.co/rmdD6zz');
  const [focused, setFocused] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('');
  const [genName, setGenName] = useState([]);

  const handleAddName = () => {
    setName(name);
    console.log(name);
  };

  const handlePlayerModal = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };

  return (
     <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={styles.keyboardContainer}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
             backgroundColor: backgroundStyle.backgroundColor,
          }}>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{title: ''}}
            validationSchema={titleSchema}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(values));
              setTimeout(() => {
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 1000);
            }}>
            {({
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit,
              isSubmitting,
              values,
              errors,
              touched,
              isValid,
            }) => (
              <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <View style={styles.teamComplete}>
                  <View>
                    <Image
                      source={require('../assets/Icons/TeamName.png')}
                      resizeMode="contain"
                      style={{
                        width: 45,
                        height: 45,
                        tintColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                 <View style={styles.teamView}>
                    <TextInput
                      style={[
                        {
                          margin: 3,
                          borderBottomColor: isValid ? '#088F8F' : '#ff0000',
                          borderBottomWidth: 1,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          padding: 5,
                          color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                        },
                        !focused && {
                          borderBottomWidth: 1,
                          borderBottomColor: colors.secondary,
                          shadowOffset: {width: 4, height: 2},
                          shadowColor: colors.primary,
                          shadowOpacity: 0.3,
                          shadowRadius: 2,
                        },
                      ]}
                      placeholder="Team Name"
                      placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
                      maxLength={14}
                      inputMode="text"
                      onChangeText={handleChange('title')}
                      value={values.title}
                      autoFocus={false}
                      onBlur={handleBlur('title')}
                      onFocus={() => {
                        setFocused(true);
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.iconView}>
                  {values.title.length < 1 ? null : errors.title ? (
                     <Image
                      style={{height: 20, width: 20}}
                      source={require('../assets/Icons/wrong.png')}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <Image
                      style={{height: 20, width: 20}}
                      source={require('../assets/Icons/correct.png')}
                    />
                  )}
                  <Text style={styles.formikText}>
                    {touched.title && errors.title}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{marginTop: 5}}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      alignSelf: 'center',
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                    }}>
                    Team Roster
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.players}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      width: '16%',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        top: 40,
                        marginTop: -24,
                       }}>
                      {value}
                    </Text>
                    <Image
                      style={{
                        tintColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      }}
                      source={require('../assets/Icons/Jersey.png')}
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      borderLeftColor: isDarkMode
                        ? Colors.lighter
                        : Colors.darker,
                      borderLeftWidth: 1,
                      width: '28%',
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        marginLeft: 5,
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}>
                  Name
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    marginLeft: 5,
                    fontSize: 20,
                    color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                  }}>
                  {name}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  borderLeftColor: isDarkMode
                    ? Colors.lighter
                    : Colors.darker,
                  borderLeftWidth: 1,
                  width: '28%',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 5,
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                  }}>
                  Position
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    marginLeft: 5,
                    color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                  }}>
                  ...
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View
                style={{
                  justifyContent: 'center',
                  borderLeftColor: isDarkMode
                    ? Colors.lighter
                    : Colors.darker,
                  borderLeftWidth: 1,
                  width: '28%',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginLeft: 5,
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                  }}>
                  Lineup
                </Text>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: 'center',
                    marginLeft: 5,
                    color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                  }}>
                  ...
                </Text>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{left: -20, top: -23}}
                onPress={() => setIsVisible(true)}>
                <Icon
                  name="add-circle-outline"
                  size={25}
                  color={isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              {
                <AddPlayer
                  visible={visible}
                  onClose={handlePlayerModal}
                  name={name}
                  handleAddName={handleAddName}
                />
              }
            </View>
                    {isSubmitting ? (
                      <ActivityIndicator
                        animating={true}
                        size="large"
                        color="purple"
                       />
                    ) : (
                      <FlatButton
                        text="submit"
                        onPress={
                          handleSubmit as unknown as (
                             e: GestureResponderEvent,
                          ) => void
                        }
                      />
                    )}
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    },
    teamComplete: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginTop: 10,
    },
    teamView: {
    width: '70%',
    },
    iconView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginLeft: 2,
    marginTop: 3,
    },
    formikText: {
    color: '#ff0000',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginLeft: 10,
    },
    keyboardContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    },
    players: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    backgroundColor: 'purple',
    marginTop: 8,
    borderRadius: 8,
    },
    playerImage: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    },
   });

   export default HomeTeamInfo;
```

Here is my AddPlayer.tsx code which is a Child Component in HomeTeamInfo.tsx, and in turn has the other three Child Components (AwayTeamInfo.tsx, Position.tsx and LineUp.tsx) from which I also expect to get the value from...

```
import React, {FC, memo, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Alert,
  Image,
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Modal,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  useColorScheme,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon1 from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import AwayTeamInfo from '../TeamInfoRec/AwayTeamInfo';
import Position from '../TeamInfoRec/Position';
import LineUp from '../TeamInfoRec/LineUp';
import {colors} from '../TeamInfoRec/colors';

export type AddPlayerProps = {
  onClose: () => void;
  visible: boolean;
  name: string;
  handleAddName: () => void;
};

const AddPlayer: FC<AddPlayerProps> = ({
  onClose, 
  visible, 
  handleAddName}) => {

  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const [focused, setFocused] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('');
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<string>('');

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={visible}
      onRequestClose={onClose}
      transparent
      animationType="slide">
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <View style={styles.addContainer}>
              <View
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: backgroundStyle.backgroundColor,
                  padding: 18,
                  top: 2,
                  width: '90%',
                  height: 400,
                  borderRadius: 20,
                  shadowColor: '#000',
                  shadowOffset: {
                  width: 0,
                  height: 2,
                  },
                  shadowOpacity: 0.25,
                  shadowRadius: 4,
                  elevation: 5,
                }}>
                <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
                    onPress={onClose}>
                    <Icon1
                      name="close"
                      size={25}
                      color={isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                  <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 22,
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}>
                      Player's Info
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.firstTextInput}>
                    <View style={{width: '25%', left: -26, zIndex: 3}}>
                      <AwayTeamInfo />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{width: '60%', paddingRight: -29}}>
                      <TextInput
                        style={{
                          fontSize: 20,
                          borderBottomColor: focused
                            ? colors.primary
                            : colors.secondary,
                            borderBottomWidth: 2,
                          left: -5,
                          paddingRight: -33,
                        }}
                        autoCapitalize="words"
                        placeholder="Name"
                        maxLength={16}
                        placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
                        value={name}
                        onFocus={() => {
                          setFocused(true);
                        }}
                        onBlur={() => {
                          setFocused(false);
                        }}
                        onChangeText={name => setName(name)}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                      {name !== '' && (
                        <TouchableOpacity
                          style={{left: 25}}
                          onPress={() => setName('')}>
                          <Image
                            style={{
                              height: 25,
                              width: 25,
                              top: 2,
                              left: -13,
                              tintColor: isDarkMode
                                ? Colors.lighter
                                : Colors.darker,
                            }}
                            source={require('../assets/Icons/clear.png')}
                          />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                      )}
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <View
                      style={{
                        width: '32%',
                        left: -111,
                        marginTop: 35,
                        zIndex: 2,
                      }}>
                      <Position />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <View
                      style={{width: '45%', left: -91, marginTop: 87, zIndex: 1}}>
                      <LineUp />
                    </View>
                  </View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    disabled={name === ''}
                    onPress={handleAddName}
                    style={{
                      borderRadius: 8,
                      paddingVertical: 10,
                      paddingHorizontal: 60,
                      backgroundColor: 'blue',
                      top: 88,
                      left: 74,
                    }}>
                    <View>
                      <Text
                        style={{
                          color: 'white',
                          fontWeight: 'bold',
                          fontSize: 16,
                          textAlign: 'center',
                        }}>
                        SAVE
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </Modal>
     );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      addContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
      },
      modalContent: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
      firstTextInput: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: 10,
      },
    });

    export default memo(AddPlayer);
```

You can have a look to the image descriptions in the following links...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jovS1.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y64bB.jpg

Comment: Question need formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AddPlayer.tsx is the HomeTeamInfo.tsx Child Component you need to initialize the States in the HomeTeamInfo.tsx Component and pass the Props all the way down to the Child (AddPlayer.tsx) and the GrandChildren (AwayTeamInfo.tsx, Position.tsx, and LineUp.tsx) Components where is needed. In addition, you also need to create and pass a function as a Callback all the way down to all the Components (Child and GrandChildren) that you want to be able to change the State from as shown below...

HomeTeamInfo.tsx (Parent Component):

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Alert,
  GestureResponderEvent,
  Image,
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  useColorScheme,
} from 'react-native';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import TeamLogo from '../assets/Icons/TeamLogo1.png';
import {Formik} from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import FlatButton from './Button';
import {colors} from './colors';
import {NativeStackScreenProps} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {RootStackParamList} from '../StackFirst/ScreenMode';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import AddPlayer from '../PlayersPick/AddPlayer';

type propsType = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'HomeTeamInfo'>;

const HomeTeamInfo = (props: propsType) => {

  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const [name, setName] = useState<string>('');
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>('');
  const [valuePosition, setValuePosition] = useState<string | null>('');
  const [lineup, setLineup] = useState<string | null>('');

  const handleAddName = () => {
    if (name.trim().length < 3) {
      return Alert.alert(
        'WARNING! Name must be at least three characters long.',
      );
    }
    setValue(value);
    setName(name);
    setValuePosition(valuePosition);
    setLineup(lineup);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(name);
    console.log(valuePosition);
    console.log(lineup);
    handlePlayerModal();
  };

  const handlePlayerModal = () => {
    setIsVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={styles.keyboardContainer}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            paddingHorizontal: 10,
            backgroundColor: backgroundStyle.backgroundColor,
          }}>
          <Formik
            initialValues={{title: ''}}
            validationSchema={titleSchema}
            onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
              Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(values));
              setTimeout(() => {
                actions.setSubmitting(false);
              }, 1000);
            }}>
            {({
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit,
              isSubmitting,
              values,
              errors,
              touched,
              isValid,
            }) => (
              <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                <View style={styles.teamComplete}>
                  <View>
                    <Image
                      source={require('../assets/Icons/TeamName.png')}
                      resizeMode="contain"
                      style={{
                        width: 45,
                        height: 45,
                        tintColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.teamView}>
                    <TextInput
                      style={[
                        {
                          margin: 3,
                          borderBottomColor: isValid ? '#088F8F' : '#ff0000',
                          borderBottomWidth: 1,
                          fontSize: 20,
                          padding: 5,
                          color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                        },
                        !focused && {
                          borderBottomWidth: 1,
                          borderBottomColor: colors.secondary,
                          shadowOffset: {width: 4, height: 2},
                          shadowColor: colors.primary,
                          shadowOpacity: 0.3,
                          shadowRadius: 2,
                        },
                      ]}
                      placeholder="Team Name"
                      placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
                      maxLength={14}
                      inputMode="text"
                      onChangeText={handleChange('title')}
                      value={values.title}
                      autoFocus={false}
                      onBlur={handleBlur('title')}
                      onFocus={() => {
                        setFocused(true);
                      }}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.iconView}>
                  {values.title.length < 1 ? null : errors.title ? (
                    <Image
                      style={{height: 20, width: 20}}
                      source={require('../assets/Icons/wrong.png')}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <Image
                      style={{height: 20, width: 20}}
                      source={require('../assets/Icons/correct.png')}
                    />
                  )}
                  <Text style={styles.formikText}>
                    {touched.title && errors.title}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={{marginTop: 5}}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      alignSelf: 'center',
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                    }}>
                    Team Roster
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.players}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      width: '16%',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        top: 40,
                        left: 1,
                        marginTop: -24,
                      }}>
                      {value}
                    </Text>
                    <Image
                      style={{
                        tintColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                      }}
                      source={require('../assets/Icons/Jersey.png')}
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      borderLeftColor: isDarkMode
                        ? Colors.lighter
                        : Colors.darker,
                      borderLeftWidth: 1,
                      width: '28%',
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        marginLeft: 5,
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}>
                      Name
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        marginLeft: 5,
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}>
                      {name}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      borderLeftColor: isDarkMode
                        ? Colors.lighter
                        : Colors.darker,
                      borderLeftWidth: 1,
                      width: '28%',
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        marginLeft: 5,
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}>
                      Position
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        marginLeft: 5,
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}>
                      {valuePosition}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      borderLeftColor: isDarkMode
                        ? Colors.lighter
                        : Colors.darker,
                      borderLeftWidth: 1,
                      width: '28%',
                    }}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        marginLeft: 5,
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}>
                      Lineup
                    </Text>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        alignSelf: 'center',
                        marginLeft: 5,
                        color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                      }}>
                      {lineup}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    style={{left: -20, top: -23}}
                    onPress={() => setIsVisible(true)}>
                    <Icon
                      name="add-circle-outline"
                      size={25}
                      color={isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker}
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  {
                    <AddPlayer
                      visible={visible}
                      onClose={handlePlayerModal}
                      handleAddName={handleAddName}
                      value={value}
                      setValue={setValue}
                      name={name}
                      setName={name => setName(name)}
                      valuePosition={valuePosition}
                      setValuePosition={setValuePosition}
                      lineup={lineup}
                      setLineup={setLineup}
                    />
                  }
                </View>
                {isSubmitting ? (
                  <ActivityIndicator
                    animating={true}
                    size="large"
                    color="purple"
                  />
                ) : (
                  <FlatButton
                    text="submit"
                    onPress={
                      handleSubmit as unknown as (
                        e: GestureResponderEvent,
                      ) => void
                    }
                  />
                )}
              </View>
            )}
          </Formik>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default HomeTeamInfo;
```

AddPlayer.tsx (Child Component):

```
import React, {FC, memo, useState} from 'react';
import {
  GestureResponderEvent,
  Image,
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Modal,
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  useColorScheme,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon1 from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import AwayTeamInfo from '../TeamInfoRec/AwayTeamInfo';
import Position from '../TeamInfoRec/Position';
import LineUp from '../TeamInfoRec/LineUp';
import {colors} from '../TeamInfoRec/colors';
import {Button} from '@rneui/themed';
import Icon2 from 'react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign';

export type AddPlayerProps = {
  onClose: () => void;
  visible: boolean;
  handleAddName: () => void;
  value: string | null;
  setValue: (value: React.SetStateAction<string | null>) => void;
  name: string;
  setName: (value: React.SetStateAction<string>) => void;
  valuePosition: string | null;
  setValuePosition: (
    valuePosition: React.SetStateAction<string | null>,
  ) => void;
  lineup: string | null;
  setLineup: (lineup: React.SetStateAction<string | null>) => void;
};

const AddPlayer: FC<AddPlayerProps> = ({
  onClose,
  visible,
  handleAddName,
  value,
  setValue,
  name,
  setName,
  valuePosition,
  setValuePosition,
  lineup,
  setLineup,
}) => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const [focused, setFocused] = useState<boolean>(false);

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={visible}
      onRequestClose={onClose}
      transparent
      animationType="slide">
      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={{flex: 1}}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <View style={styles.addContainer}>
            <View
              style={{
                backgroundColor: backgroundStyle.backgroundColor,
                padding: 18,
                top: 2,
                width: '90%',
                height: 400,
                borderRadius: 20,
                shadowColor: '#000',
                shadowOffset: {
                  width: 0,
                  height: 2,
                },
                shadowOpacity: 0.25,
                shadowRadius: 4,
                elevation: 5,
              }}>
              <View style={{alignItems: 'flex-end'}}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
                  onPress={onClose}>
                  <Icon1
                    name="close"
                    size={25}
                    color={isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker}
                  />
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.modalContent}>
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 22,
                      fontWeight: 'bold',
                      color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
                    }}>
                    Player's Info
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.firstTextInput}>
                  <View style={{width: '25%', left: -26, zIndex: 3}}>
                    <AwayTeamInfo value={value} setValue={setValue} />
                  </View>
                  <View style={{width: '60%', paddingRight: -29}}>
                    <TextInput
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 20,
                        borderBottomColor: focused
                          ? colors.primary
                          : colors.secondary,
                        borderBottomWidth: 2,
                        left: -5,
                        paddingRight: -33,
                      }}
                      autoCapitalize="words"
                      placeholder="Name"
                      maxLength={16}
                      placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
                      value={name}
                      onFocus={() => {
                        setFocused(true);
                      }}
                      onBlur={() => {
                        setFocused(false);
                      }}
                      onChangeText={name => setName(name)}
                    />
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    {name !== '' && (
                      <TouchableOpacity
                        style={{left: 25}}
                        onPress={() => setName('')}>
                        <Image
                          style={{
                            height: 25,
                            width: 25,
                            top: 2,
                            left: -13,
                            tintColor: isDarkMode
                              ? Colors.lighter
                              : Colors.darker,
                          }}
                          source={require('../assets/Icons/clear.png')}
                        />
                      </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                  </View>
                </View>

                <View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      width: '32%',
                      left: -111,
                      marginTop: 35,
                      zIndex: 2,
                    }}>
                    <Position
                      valuePosition={valuePosition}
                      setValuePosition={setValuePosition}
                    />
                  </View>
                </View>

                <View>
                  <View
                    style={{width: '45%', left: -91, marginTop: 87, zIndex: 1}}>
                    <LineUp lineup={lineup} setLineup={setLineup} />
                  </View>
                </View>
                <View
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: 8,
                    paddingVertical: 10,
                    paddingHorizontal: 20,
                    top: 70,
                    left: 74,
                  }}>
                  <Button
                    buttonStyle={{height: 50, width: 160}}
                    icon={<Icon2 name="save" size={26} color="white" />}
                    radius={'lg'}
                    size="lg"
                    color={'secondary'}
                    title="SAVE"
                    titleStyle={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                    }}
                    type="solid"
                    disabled={
                      name.trim() === '' ||
                      name.trim().length < 3 ||
                      value === '' ||
                      valuePosition === '' ||
                      lineup === ''
                    }
                    disabledStyle={{borderColor: '#AD1457', borderWidth: 3}}
                    onPress={
                      handleAddName as unknown as (
                        e: GestureResponderEvent,
                      ) => void
                    }
                  />
                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default memo(AddPlayer);
```

AwayTeamInfo.tsx (GrandChild Component):

```
import React, {FC, memo, useState} from 'react';
import {Image, StyleSheet, View, useColorScheme} from 'react-native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

export type DropProps = {
  value: string | null;
  setValue: (value: React.SetStateAction<string | null>) => void;
};

const AwayTeamInfo: FC<DropProps> = ({
  value,
  setValue,
}) => {

  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      label: '',
      value: '0',
      icon: () => (
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/Icons/Jerseys/0.png')}
          style={styles.iconStyle}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      label: '',
      value: '1',
      icon: () => (
        <Image
          source={require('../assets/Icons/Jerseys/1.png')}
          style={styles.iconStyle}
        />
      ),
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: backgroundStyle.backgroundColor,
      }}>
      <View
        style={{
          paddingHorizontal: 2,
        }}>
        <DropDownPicker
          style={{backgroundColor: 'cyan'}}
          listItemContainerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
          }}
          iconContainerStyle={{borderRadius: 20, width: 10, marginLeft: -13}}
          showTickIcon={false}
          arrowIconStyle={{left: 11}}
          listMode="MODAL"
          open={open}
          value={value}
          items={items}
          setOpen={setOpen}
          setValue={setValue}
          setItems={setItems}
          onChangeValue={value => setValue(value)}
          placeholder={'#'}
          placeholderStyle={{
            color: 'black',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
          }}
          selectedItemLabelStyle={{color: 'green', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
          labelStyle={{
            fontSize: 24,
            color: 'green',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            marginLeft: -13,
          }}
          listParentLabelStyle={{
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'red',
            fontSize: 25,
          }}
          listChildLabelStyle={{
            color: 'red',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default memo(AwayTeamInfo);
```

Then just follow the same procedure as above with the remaining two GrandChildren (Position.tsx and LineUp.tsx), i.e. pass the missing Props (valuePosition, setValuePosition, lineup and setLineup,).

In the following links you can see how the image descriptions look like in relation to what is described above:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNkpQ.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyE1o.jpg

The source that I relied on to find a way out of my impasse was the following link...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4J00e1tkCCM

I hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).